# Comment appeler une personne faisant de la trottinette ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, transports

Pour décrire une personne faisant du **vélo**, nous utiliserons en général: Un cycliste.

> Personne qui pratique le sport du cyclisme ou qui se déplace à bicyclette.

Pour décrire une personne faisant du **skate**, nous utiliserons en général : Un skateur.

> Personne pratiquant le skateboard ou skate.

En revanche les **trottinettes** électriques devenant de plus en plus populaires, je ne trouve pas le terme désignant une personne se déplaçant à l'aide de cette dernière, ou bien d'un trottinette de manière générale.

Comment: Selon le modèle patiner->patineur je dirais trottiner->trottineur mais ce dernier n'existe pas:-)!

Answer (score 6):

On a d'abord utilisé **trottinetteur**.

> J'aime le rolleriste qui s'écrase par terre,
> et le trottinetteur qui part le cul en l'air.

Philippe Muray, *Minimum Respect*, Les Belles Lettres, 2003

mais ce sont aujourd'hui :

> **Trotirider** et **Trottirider**

qui semblent s'imposer :

> [Après le boom des trottinettes du début des années 2000, les fabricants de trottinettes se sont intéressés à ceux qu’on appelle maintenant les « trotiriders ».](https://les-trotinettes.com/trottinettes/trottinette-freestyle/)
>
> [Vocabulaire du trotirider](http://normandie-scootering.e-monsite.com/blog/vocabulair-du-trotirider.html)
>
> [Quand les jeunes trottiriders côtoient les pros.](https://www.ouest-france.fr/pays-de-la-loire/quand-les-jeunes-trottiriders-cotoient-les-pros-5631844) Ouest-France

Comment: Haha j'imagine déjà la réaction de l'Académie Française

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Elle suggérera peut-être *Trottirailledeur*... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Le terme [trottineur](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8875339) est déjà employé pour rendre le *toddler* et on a déjà parlé ailleurs du *trottinetteur*, tout à fait adéquat.

---

La personne qui pratique la planche à roulette est un [*(rouli)planchiste*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8412193), le skater/skateur n'étant rien d'autre qu'un calque du terme anglais. [Franceterme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=planchiste&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) dispose de *planchiste* pour le pratiquant d'un sport de planche pour rendre *boarder* et liste aéroplanchiste (*skyboarder*), aquaplanchiste (*boardsurfer*), nivoplanchiste (*snowboarder*) et véliplanchiste (*windsurfer*) : il est facile d'imaginer *trottiplanchiste*. Par ailleurs la trottinette peut s'appeler *push/kick scooter* en anglais, de sorte que le sens du terme [*scootériste*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/scoot%C3%A9riste) pourrait être étendu. Enfin on peut utiliser un synonyme de trottinette, soit la [patinette](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/patinette/58665?q=patinette#58306) : reste à déterminer si on veut patinett[iste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-iste) ou patinett[eur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-eur) les deux suffixes étant employés dans le domaine des sports. L'apport de l'anglicisme [*rider*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rider#Nom_commun) fait double-emploi (et relève davantage du poseur que du sportif à mon avis).

---

En résumé un **planchiste** d'un type particulier, peut-être un **trottiplanchiste** ; un **scootériste** si on en étendait le sens ; ou un terme employant patinette adéquatement suffixé (-iste, -eur), **patinettiste/eur**.

Comment: Heureusement que personne n'a rien contre les norvégianismes sinon les skieurs deviendraient des binivoplanchistes...

Comment: @LaurentS. ...coexiste d'abord avec l'anglicisme _skier_ « soldat chaussé de skis » et a éliminé _patineur_ (encore patineur en ski, 1902)... (DHLF) donc je m'y oppose et exige une restitution intégrale de _patineur en ski_ ahahhahah. Toi et moi on a à quelques occasions « échangé » sur le sujet. Quand j'étais enfant j'avais un ami Belge et l'anglais était complètement absent chez eux, mais on était enfants. C'est très récent ma compréhension des communautés linguistiques de Belgique, et l'idée que peut-être l'anglais sert à se comprendre dans ce cadre ? Je ne comprends pas _binivo-_.

Comment: En général, je suis très pointilleux avec l'écrit. À l'oral j'emploie constamment des anglicismes, malheureusement. Aujourd'hui par exemple je ne me souvenais plus comment dire _shipment_ en français. À l'écrit je préfère une approche systématique où il y a cohérence et qui s'appuie sur le construit de la langue, plutôt que de réinventer la planche constamment. Je déteste avoir l'impression qu'on ne connaît pas le lexique et qu'on valorise une langue étrangère comme si ses mots étaient plus porteurs que ceux de la nôtre. Remarque je n'ai aucune expertise et c'est sans prétention. Salut !

Comment: Ah, ok, _nivobiplanchiste_ hahahh.

Answer (score 1):

Ça n'est évidemment pas un terme du dictionnaire, mais un revendeur bien connu utilise le terme [Trottrider](https://www.oxelo.fr/conseils/le-lexique-du-trottrider-a_2639).

Answer (score 0):

La réalité décrite dans la question, une personne faisant de la trottinette, n'est que marginalement lexicalisée en français.  On emploie le plus souvent une périphrase.

Pour ma part, si je voyais passer une personne faisant de la trottinette, je dirais « un mec en trottinette », comme dans :

- Y a un mec en trottinette, il est passé au rouge.

ou :

- Ils font vraiment chier tous ces cons en trottinette à rouler sur les trottoirs !

Answer (score 0):

À noter également que l'on parle beaucoup de *Riders* ou *Freestylers* pour les personnes qui ont des trottinettes dirt, et font des [figures freestyle](https://matrott.com/figures-de-base-trottinette-freestyle/) dans les skate parks.